# default prediction. What does a model look like?

Tags: classification

There is a data set in the ISLR package that deals with student loan defaults
You basically have 3 predictor columns: credit card balance, whether or not individual is a student, and the balance of the loan. The fourth column tells us whether or not the individual defaulted.

I was able to get code that used LDA to form a separatrix(maybe wrong term here) between defaulters and non defaulters. It made a train test split(.7 and .3 respectively) and ran LDA on the test set after training on train set.

In linear regression, you basically find an equation that you can use to make predictions. What is the analog here? How would I go about classifying future data based on the model
There is no formula so what is there? And how would such a model be deployed ?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the code uses LDA in a supervised setting. Can you explain what it does in more detail or share the code?

Comment: it uses LDA to find a line (hyperplane) that best separates the defaulters vs the non defaulters